# htaccess rewrite url rule

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm new to htaccess and I need some help with a rewrite rule.

I wish to rewrite:

```
/all-accomodation/anything/ to: /portfolio-gallery/anything/
```

The 'anything' could be any slug.

One thing to note is that I have a page with a slug of 'all-accomodation' and when requested by itself shouldn't rewrite.

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to edit Wordpress's rewrite. Above that block, you can try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^all-accomodation/(.+)(/?) /portfolio-gallery/$1$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will 301 redirect all requests.

Comment: Great, thanks Rob. Is there anyway I can have it just rewrite, i.e no 301? I want to keep the URL as /all-accomodation/cottages/ but serve the page: /portfolio-gallery/cottages/

Comment: Also, just a note here, this assumes that THAT path is not a real directory path (`!-d` part)

Comment: If I leave the 301 in (to test), it 301's /all-accomodation to /portfolio-gallery. /all-accomodation/cottages redirects to /portfolio-gallery/cottages as expected, but if I take out the 301, /all-accomodation/cottages 404's

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Rob, still getting a 404, could it be because wordpress is also rewriting to index.php?

Comment: Yes it was wordpress rules, have sorted, thanks again for your help +1 and marked as answer ;)